# Java: Runnables and execution of methods. Where should they be?Does it matter?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, concurrency, executorservice

If I use an executor to submit tasks as follows:

```
public SomeClass{  

     public void doSomething(){  

            Runnable r = new Runnable(){  
                 public void run(){  
                    callSomeMethod();  
                 }   

            }   

            executor.execute(r);  

    }  

}
```

Does it make any difference if `callSomeMethod` is

- a private method of the `Runnable r` or
- a method of `SomeClass` in any way related to *concurrency* issues?

I am not refering to access of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are subtle differences, but it should not matter to you.

If callSomeMethod() is private and declared in the enclosing (outer) class, JVM specification would deny the anonymous Runnable access to it (Private methods are only visible to the declaring class. The concept of inner classes is unknown to the VM).
However, by the language specification, this is a valid call. The java compiler does some magic in this case - it generates a synthetic accessor (basically a method not declared in the source, but purely generated by the compiler, to enable access to the private method).

The same happens for class members that are private. So strictly speaking there is a difference, it will enlarge the resulting class file(s) a  tiny bit.

You should choose whatever form is most appropiate it terms of code readability. The Runnable can be viewed as part of the method (and thus its containing class), so if callSomeMethod() is private to the class declaring class, it should be declared private.

As to where to best put callSomeMethod(), make that decision based on what its purpose is/what it does (where you would logically expect to find the operation performed by the code).

Comment: +1:The part on the "performance"/size due to compiler automatic modification was a point I was interested in.If you also have some concrete examples/suggestions on readability it would also be highly appreciated

Comment: For the readability part; I don't think there is an established best practice where to place Runnable declarations. The only thing that comes to mind is the more general question of where to place anonymous inner classes (and when to use them at all). Maybe you should ask this as a separate question; a good title would certainly get better responses on that than I could ever hope to give.

Answer (score 2):

Very very abstractly speaking (this is what you asked for), there is no difference. A method is just a piece of code. When a thread executes a method, a copy of that method exists on the thread's private stack, regardless of where the code was actually defined.

Accessing shared variables and scoping is an entirely different discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't access any variables, how could you have *concurrency* issues?

Comment: I want access to variables.I was wondering if there are any issues non-related to shared variables